# Preventing camera to save a file till all my processing is done in Titanium SDK

Tags: android, ios, camera, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using titanium sdk for mobile app development.

I was just searching for any way that i can prevent the camera from saving the image. I dont want to save the image till a few steps down the line so that all the information has been verified.

What i mean to say is that suppose after after clicking the image through the app if user selects the cancel button the image should not be present in the gallery.

Functionality is needed both on IOS and android.

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: If you are saving the image in sd card, just delete it on cancel button click.

Comment: Sd might be valid in android. But in case of IOS there is not sdcard.

Comment: So, you will be saving it in data directory, you can delete it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the saveToPhotoGallery to false and on the success function of the Titanium.Media.showCamera() put your logic and when they click on the save button save to the gallery

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(event) {
        // called when media returned from the camera
        Ti.API.debug('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
            //
            //add your logic here
            //

            //onSave
            Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(event.media);
        } else {
            alert("got the wrong type back ="+event.mediaType);
        }
    },
    cancel:function() {
        // called when user cancels taking a picture
    },
    error:function(error) {
        // called when there's an error
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
            a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
        } else {
            a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }
        a.show();
    },
    saveToPhotoGallery: false,
    allowEditing: true,
    mediaTypes: [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
});
```